# Confusion with spectral density of the emitted power of blackbody radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electrons, thermal-radiation, signal-processing

I'm reading a book discussing electrons' velocity fluctuations, which would cause electronic noise when detecting signals.

> Velocity fluctuations originate from thermal motion.  Superimposed on the average drift velocity are random velocity fluctuations due to thermal excitation.
>
> ...
>
> the maximum power that can be extracted from a thermal component in equilibrium by applying Planck's theory of blackbody radiation. The energy per mode at an absolute temperature $T$ as a function of frequency $f$ is
> $$\overline E=\frac{hf}{e^{hf/kT}-1}\quad(1)$$
> Since $E=\int P\;\!\mathrm{d}t$, the spectral density of the emitted power
> $$\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm df}=\frac{hf}{e^{hf/kT}-1}\quad (2)$$
> This is the power that can be extracted in equilibrium.
>
> *Handbook of Particle Detection and Imaging* P42.

I'm confused about the derivation and meaning of $\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm df}$. Why does
$E=\int P\;\!\mathrm{d}t$ lead to $\overline{E}=\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm df}$?

What does "the power that can be extracted in equilibrium" stand for?

Comment: have you heard of impedance matching?

Comment: @hyportnex . I read about transmission lines before. Do you mean the impedance at the end of the line to prevent reflections?

Comment: yes, that one. imagine every mode is matched to a terminated transmission line without reflection, that gives you the extractable power per unit frequency in equilibrium; and you have thermal equilibrium when the termination is at the the same temperature as the black body (source).